# Argument of type 'Omit<P, "prop1"> & { prop1: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'P'

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a higher order function which can add some lines of code before and after the invocation and generate an extra value which needs to be shared with the wrapped function.

My code looks like the following right now.

```js
interface Interface1 {
  prop1: string;
}

const func1 = <P extends Interface1>(func2: (param: P) => any) => {
  const str = 'something';
  return (param: Omit<P, 'prop1'>) => { // Getting type error on this line
    return func2({ ...param, prop1: str });
  };
};
```

So in the above code I am receiving a type error

```
Argument of type 'Omit<P, "prop1"> & { prop1: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'P'.
  'Omit<P, "prop1"> & { prop1: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Interface1'
```

I don't understand why can't `Omit<P, "prop1"> & { prop1: string; }` be equivalent of `P` here. Is this some sort of weird TypeScript issue, or is there something wrong that I am doing here. Of course I can just add `as P` to enforce the type, but I wanna understand why it's failing right now. Any idea?

Comment: See the answer to the linked question.  The compiler can't do higher order type analysis like this very well, so if you're sure you're doing it right then feel free to use a type assertion.  But note that the compiler is technically right to complain; it's not type safe if someone passes in a `P` where `prop1` is narrower than `string`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBkYkm).